# Error RZ3007: Targeted tag name cannot be null or whitespace

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, runtime-error, asp.net-core-2.0

After upgrading to .NET Core 2.0 my 1.1 web application cannot run.  I get the error message indicated below.  After checking the output I found references to the RZ3007 error which I believe is related to the Razor compiler.  The View is not compiling.

Home/Index.cshtml:

```
@model LayoutViewModel
<div></div>
```

Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - GLCoderConfiguration</title>

    <environment names="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css?" />
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css?" asp-append-version="true" />

   </environment>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-form " >

        <div class="navbar-header" style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:15px;">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SCM - NCMain</a>
        </div>


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse vcenter" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:0px;">

      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2017 - England Logisitics - SCM</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <environment names="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>


    </environment>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
  </body>
</html>
```

I had a couple of view components (LoginStatus and MenuItems) but removed them to try to get this working.

Output from run:

```
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.CompilationFailedException: One or more compilation failures occurred:
(0,0): Error RZ3007: Targeted tag name cannot be null or whitespace.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(String relativePath)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CreateCacheEntry(String normalizedPath)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider.CreateFactory(String relativePath)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.CreateCacheResult(HashSet`1 expirationTokens, String relativePath, Boolean isMainPage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.OnCacheMiss(ViewLocationExpanderContext expanderContext, ViewLocationCacheKey cacheKey)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.LocatePageFromViewLocations(ActionContext actionContext, String pageName, Boolean isMainPage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, String viewName, Boolean isMainPage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.CompositeViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, String viewName, Boolean isMainPage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor.FindView(ActionContext actionContext, ViewResult viewResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.<ExecuteResultAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.<Invoke>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.<Invoke>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

.CSProj

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
        <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
        <MvcCompileViews>true</MvcCompileViews>
        <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
        <AssetTargetFallback>$(AssetTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</AssetTargetFallback>
        <StartupObject>GLCoderConfiguration.Program</StartupObject>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="7.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="NETStandard.Library" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" Version="4.4.0" />
      </ItemGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\..\SCMEnumerations\SCMEnumerations.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\..\TMainModel\TMainModel.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\..\ViewHelperFunctions\ViewExtensions.csproj" />
      </ItemGroup>

    </Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going over the steps detailed from [Microsoft.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/)  I then uninstalled Visual Studio completely and reinstalled.  Then I created a new web project, set it to target 2.0 and then copied the files from the non-working solution and things started working automatically.  I still need to ensure Authentication is configured correctly but things are beginning to fall in line.

Comment: Hi @dmcquay, I also had this problem, and also had to recreate my project from scratch to fix the problem, which we shouldn't have to do... I've just recently found the issue again, with seamingly no reason to have done so... upon looking through my git repo and comparing changes between the last successful build!

Did you ever learn any additional info about this error? I've spent way too much time with these sorts of errors with my stock standard dot net core dev environment.

Answer (score 3):

This method worked for me:

- delete `obj` and `bin` folders
- run `dotnet restore`
- run `dotnet build`

Comment: This worked for me as well. ```dotnet --version 2.1.200```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace  `environment names` with `environment include` like.

```
<environment include="Staging,Production">
  <strong>HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName is Staging or Production</strong>
</environment>
```

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/environmenttaghelper):

> The `include` property (in ASP.NET Core 2.0) has a similar behavior of the `names` attribute in
>   ASP.NET Core 1.0.

**UPDATE:**
Tried to migrate some of my projects myself (From 1.1 to 2.0) using packages like in you `.csproj` in order to reproduce you error, but unfortunately no luck. Not sure, but maybe this caused by precompilation.

I had `CompilationFailedException` sometimes but it was like `CS0246` and shows lines which caused problem. But your `RZ3007`(0,0) looks like Razor itself somehow broken. Probably you should open new issue on Github. 
Not sure if helps, but alo try to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language` NuGet package, because it seems to be needed if you [read this discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/227) about Razor changes.

Also try to update Visual Studio 2017 to version 15.3 if you don't use it now.
Also, make sure SDK is updated to version 2.0

Comment: Tried it.  No dice.  Based on the docs I believe names attribute is still valid.

Comment: @dmcquay I see, strange. Then please update your question with the content of your `*.csproj` file.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the line below from `*.csproj` fixed it for me

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />`

I had added it in after reading the *Review your Razor View Compilation setting* section in the [upgrade documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/). Turns out it wasn't a good idea to add it!

Answer (score 0):

In `Startup` class `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method in pre-netcore-2.0 versions a workaround was needed:

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddApplicationPart(typeof(SomeController).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
        .AddRazorOptions(options =>
        {
            // By docs this should work out of the box, but due to a bug this workaround is needed currently:
            foreach (var name in typeof(Program).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
                    options.AdditionalCompilationReferences.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Load(name).Location));
        })
        ;
```

But not anymore. The following is enough:

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddApplicationPart(typeof(SomeController).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

Leaving the workaround in causes the mentioned RZ3007 error.

Comment: Where does the TowerController come from in this answer?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the wording to "SomeController", meaning any controller.

Answer (score 0):

In my case disabling this Razor setting in.csproj worked:

```
<PropertyGroup>   
<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this in my *csproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
   <Reference Include="System.Private.Xml">
     <HintPath>C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.0\System.Private.Xml.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
 </ItemGroup>
```

Have no idea where it came from, but removing it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When publishing from visual studio 2019 I checked **Remove additional files at destination** publish option and that solved this issue.

[image]