# error rz3007: targeted tag name cannot be null or whitespace. site:stackoverflow.com

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying upgrade to asp .net core v.2.0.1 but All of a sudden I get this strange bug.. I have upgraded visual studio too... (v 15.7.2 - could be the problem.)

My index page, is very simple, and only forwards to another page, so it is easily changed.... but that doesn't have any effect. My guess is that the problem is is really what exception explains...

I cannot figure out why though, or how to workaround it... Here is my index page:

```
@page @model SRC.Pages.IndexModel

@using System.Net.Mime
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions
@using SRC.Pages

<p>
    my Index
</p>
```

and the model behind:

```
namespace SRC.Pages
{ 
     public class IndexModel : PageModel
     {
        public void OnGet()
        {
          // TODO KFN
        }
     }
}
```

a very fancy index page model ;-) - that fails to react correctly to show the text... - the terminal writes the bug

### Anyone got any ideas?

as suggested in Dot Net Core Build Error on Publish - Targeted tag name cannot be null or whitespace
 - I've tried cleaning the bin/obj folders.. - no effect 
 - Publish again.. - no effect

Comment: The exception is thrown from line 49 in DefaultPageLoader.cs
in 

      namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal

where it states:

        var viewDescriptor = compileTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Comment: I got around it somehow, but I cannot recalll how..

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you've tried all the proposed solutions from [another post with the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799547/error-rz3007-targeted-tag-name-cannot-be-null-or-whitespace) and they didn't work.

Another thing that can generate this error is the Azure's Web App going corrupt (like some server's dll not updating with the new version). An easy way around it is to publish the project onto a new Web App.

Comment: maybee that was all, I cannot remember. (i.e. deleting my output folders manually)